# AFNetworking + Multiple NSOperationQueues + progress

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking, uiprogressview

I have an application that I'm working on that has a UITableView. Each cell has a download button that is supposed to download several files that are tied to that cell. I want to be able to track the progress of each queue that is downloading the cell's files. Has anyone had experience with this kind of task before, and can you point me to a tutorial on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is not to have separate operation queues. You need a separate operation for each download and pass a block to the operation's `setDownloadProgressBlock:` to track the progress of the download. Take a look at [this link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) for more information (How do I track upload or download progress?).

Comment: @BartJacobs the problem with that approach is that I need to keep track of each cell's progress independently and each cell has several downloads to maintain. I have looked at the help docs already.

Comment: @ErikRodriguez: I'm having trouble with this for uploading. But I don't see why downloading would be a problem.  You can find many tutorials to download 1 file. You just need to associate different progressView for each download.

Comment: @Eugene Single File per cell I can do, but when I have multiple files per cell to download is what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try attaching enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests to each cell.

Comment: that was the thing I was looking for. Thanks!